# What is `HtmlString` used for in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

This class: [HtmlString](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Support/HtmlString.html)

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Support;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Htmlable;

class HtmlString implements Htmlable
{
    /**
     * The HTML string.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $html;

    /**
     * Create a new HTML string instance.
     *
     * @param  string  $html
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($html)
    {
        $this->html = $html;
    }

    /**
     * Get the HTML string.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function toHtml()
    {
        return $this->html;
    }

    /**
     * Get the HTML string.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->toHtml();
    }
}
```

use:

```
    function csrf_field()
    {
        return new HtmlString('<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="'.csrf_token().'">');
    }
```

It does nothing but "construct" an string and return the string itself!

Can anyone explain it? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 13):

Since it implements an interface (`Htmlable`), other methods can potentially check whether a string it's been given should be treated as HTML or not.

It's not used that much, but for instance in `Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:519`:

```
if (! function_exists('e')) {
    /**
     * Escape HTML special characters in a string.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Htmlable|string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    function e($value)
    {
        if ($value instanceof Htmlable) {
            return $value->toHtml();
        }

        return htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
    }
}
```

Here, you can see that if the `$value` adhers to the `Htmlable` interface, it can be printed right away. Otherwise, the string is printed in escaped form.

Comment: Yes, an instance where you might use HtmlString would be if you are actually composing HTML (perhaps using Parsedown or storing actual HTML in the database) you can inject the string into the view as an HtmlString instead of text, and it will skip the escaping (essentially using `{{ $variable }}` instead of having to use `{!! $variable !!}`).  You will need to ensure that you can trust the source of the text, however, which is the reason the escaping exists in the first place.

Answer (score -3):

If I understand good,you want to use it in a `.blade.php` file?
use

```
{{csrf_field()}}
```

Comment: Of course it is used like you said XD, but I'm curious about the HtmlString class under that, thanks for your time.

Comment: notice how `csrf_field()` returns `HtmlString`, so in blade you can print with `{{ ... }}` instead of `{!! ... !!}`. No need to remember to print raw and ensures it doesn't get escaped